# How to remove foreign key without constraint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have reference my `NotificaionSourceId` with Help table Id but I need to remove this since I no longer want to reference this two columns anymore but I'm not really sure how I can remove the reference so If I can get any help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Notification] WITH CHECK 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY([NotificationSourceId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Help]([Id])
```

I saw many people do like this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[company] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [Company_CountryID_FK]
```

but I don't have the FK key so I'm lost.

Comment: Dropping the column should also drop any constraints on it. Also, are you using SQLite or Microsoft SQL Server? You've tagged both. Looks like SQL Server.

Comment: @Schwern Oh I don't want to drop the NotificationSourceId tho, I still want it in my table but it's just I don't want that to reference to anything. so please help :(

Comment: Sorry this is SQL Server.

Comment: So, as a strong suggestion, ALWAYS name your constraints. I learned this the hard way too.

Comment: See INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS.

Answer (score 0):

use query below to find your FK name :

```
SELECT
    FK_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
    FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
    PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
    PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
    Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                i1.TABLE_NAME,
                i2.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            WHERE
                i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
           ) PT
    ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
```

then drop it using :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[company] DROP CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name]
```